# От чего зависит внешний вид option?

Tags: css, html-select

[image: От чего зависит внешний вид option?]

Для контейнера `select` в `CSS` указано:

```
select {
font-family: "PT Mono";
font-size: 18px;
padding: 0 6px;
height: 36px;
}
```

К первому (видимому) `option` применяются все правила.

А вот к остальным:

В Opera (версия 48.0.2685.35; `рис. 1`) применяется font-family, font-size и padding (правда, только горизонтальный, вертикальный, как оказалось, — нет).

В Firefox (версия 56.0; `рис. 2`) — ничего.

От чего зависит такое поведение (и, как следствие, внешний вид) `option` и можно ли на это повлиять средствами `CSS`?

Comment: Ни от чего, кроме хотелок разработчиков браузеров. [Вот это тоже option](http://www.recreateweb.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/prog-resp-nav_13.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> От чего зависит такое поведение (и, как следствие, внешний вид) option и можно ли на это повлиять средствами CSS?

Если смотреть на стандарты то - нет. Option рисуется часто средствами ОС и вы не можете никак на это повлиять. 
Если углубляться в детали, то на текущий момент браузеры по немногу отказываются от ОС спецефичных UI элементов, а другие хитро настраивают и по немногу появляется возможность стилизовать средствами css, но часто очень ограниченно.

Именно по этому уже давно, если вам что то нужно серьёзное от "select" то делаете его сами, а option становятся просто элементами списка в вашем диве. Но увы такое без JS проделать трудно, но есть и готовые решения.